# How to you code an <a href="... tag in ASPX to call a simple code behind function?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to you code an <a href="... tag in ASPX to call a simple code behind function?

I have inherited a bit of code.  I did not write this originally but I am trying to modify it.

In the steppayment.aspx file there are lots of "<a href..." tags that target either a whole URL or another aspx file.

But what if I only want to call a function in the code-behind, steppayment.aspx.cs?

In the aspx file, steppayment.aspx,  I have this line of code:

```
 <u><b><a href="fsModifyVisualContentonPaypal();" >Click here</a></b></u> now to open the PayPal payment window.
```

In the code behind, steppayment.aspx.cs, I have this line of code:

```
protected void fsModifyVisualContentonPaypal()
{
    fsCreditCard.Visible = false;
    fsAfterCreditCard.Visible = true;
}
```

I have break points in this function.  It never gets here.  When the user clicks on the "click here" it throws an error.

Comment: You can't do it that way - the code you posted is expecting a JavaScript function, not a method in the code behind.  You'll either have to have the JavaScript call the code behind or use a different control.

Answer (score 2):

Use a LinkButton control instead of a basic HTML anchor tag

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClick="fsModifyVisualContentonPaypal" runat="server" Text="Click here" />
```

To call client side methods like javascript you would use `OnClientClick`.  You'll want to check out [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for LinkButton on MSDN

Comment: your documentation says linkbutton is for javascript  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
The LinkButton control renders JavaScript to the client browser. 

and this threw an error:
<u><b><asp:LinkButton OnClick="fsModifyVisualContentonPaypal" runat="server">Click here</asp:LinkButton></b></u>

Comment: The OnClick event raises an event which is handled on the server side.  There is an example in the documentation right here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If it you want it to work on postback, try an ASP.NET LinkButton control.

This is from memory, but it would be something like this:

```
 <u><b><asp:LinkButton OnClick="fsModifyVisualContentonPaypal" runat="server">Click here</asp:LinkButton></b></u>
```

If you want it to work without a postback, that gets you into either Ajax territory or plain JavaScript.  (Or, you might look up the ASP.NET UpdatePanel.)

All of this is assuming that you're using ASP.NET WebForms.  If you're using MVC, that's another topic.

Comment: it says linkbutton is for javascript http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
The LinkButton control renders JavaScript to the client browser. 

and this threw an error:
<u><b><asp:LinkButton OnClick="fsModifyVisualContentonPaypal" runat="server">Click here</asp:LinkButton></b></u>

Answer (score 1):

Both answers would work. You need to change the event method signature as well like this:

```
protected void fsModifyVisualContentonPaypal(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fsCreditCard.Visible = false;
    fsAfterCreditCard.Visible = true;
}
```

And your link button should look like this ( as suggesested by both answers):

```
<u><b><asp:LinkButton OnClick="fsModifyVisualContentonPaypal" runat="server">Click here</asp:LinkButton></b></u>
```